# How do I redirect from one Async Action to Another (MVC5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have an Admin section to my site, where I want admin people to be able to add new users.
I also have a separate Register Link, which works.

I want to use `ajax` to update my admin section. So the plan is:

1. Admin fills in form of user info
2. `AdminController` checks if it is valid and then redirects to the `AuthenticationController` method to create the user
3. If the `AuthController` returns success, then reload the list of all users
4. return this to the partial to update the screen.

When I debug the code, I hit the Admin controller, but I cannot step into the `AuthController` to see why it is failing. (It all compiles OK)

I assume it is something to do with the fact that my two methods are both async, but I cannot await the redirect from one to the other.

Briefly, the code is;

```
[Authorize(Roles = "AccessAllAreas")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]        
public async Task<PartialViewResult> CreateNewUser(ApplicationUserViewModel avm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var foo = RedirectToAction("RegisterAsyncFromOtherController", "Account", avm);

    ....
    }

[Authorize(Roles = "AccessAllAreas")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterAsyncFromOtherController(ApplicationUserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

A break point on the above `if (Modelstate.IsValid)` is never hit. However a breakpoint and then step into on the call to `RegisterAsyncFromOtherController()` accesses one of the properties on the view model, then it returns to `CreateNewUser`. (Which is what makes me suspect that the async is not working correctly).

Is there anything wrong with the concept I have here, and what is causing the debug behaviour I am seeing?

Comment: What are you doing with the `foo` variable after that? It has disappeared into a fog of unclosed curly braces.

Comment: The redirect to method never returns, so the code after that line is irrelevent for the problem at hand.

Comment: Are you saying that after having walked the code in a debugger, or based on your assumptions? `RedirectToAction()` _does_ return, and you have to use its return value in order for it to be of any use. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I used the debugger, the redirect to just disappears into the ether.
I think your anser makes sense, so it makes me wonder if there is a better way of achieving what I want to do, or else I am returning to the browser to tell it to redirect to the account controller, and then that needs to redirect to my admin section. (Just seems a little kludgy!)

Answer (score 0):

a `RedirectToAction` should be returned to the response so the browser of the visitor can redirect to the given url. Only after that has happened will you hit the `RegisterAsyncFromOtherController` action.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're confusing `RedirectToAction()` with `Response.Redirect()`.

`RedirectToAction()` returns a `RedirectToRouteResult` (which inherits from `ActionResult`), and you have to return it to the caller in order for it to have any effect. If you don't return it, `RedirectToAction()` won't do anything?